# Combine the two different collection of mongoose after iteration based on common key and from one json and send in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

I have two collection in MongoDb and they have a relation like primary and foreign key of sql.Based on this key how to pull all the document/record from the collection and combine there data in one json/record and send.

case: collection is having schema like this

```
user:{id,role,email}
userAction:{id,user.id,post,job}
userTask:{id,user.id,job,task}
```

Now i want to pull all the data from userAction and userTask based on the user.id and form a json like this

```
[{user.id,user.role,user.email,userAction.id,userAction.post,userAction.job,userTask.id,userTask.job,userTask.task},{....}]
```

how to do this using mongoose in nodejs?

i will call the `userModel.find(query,callback)` on the user to pull the record from the `user` and after function completion successfully i will call the `userTaskModel.find(query,callback)` and `userActionModel.find(query ,callback)` inside it. I will have the one `userdata=[];` where i will `push` all the record after forming into one json and send this `userdata` array in `response.json(userdata);` to user.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can reference `userTask` and `userAction` in user, then populate them. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the solution till mongoose version 4.10.8

`async` and `output.toObject()`  done the real job for me

```
const express = require("express");
const async = require("async");
const router = express.Router();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var UsersDb=mongoose.model('user');  
var userAction = mongoose.model("useraction");  
router.get("/emp/:id", (req, res, next) => {
      let userData = [];
      UsersDb.find({id:req.params.id},(err,results)=>{

        async.forEach(results,(element,callback)=>{
        userAction.findById({userid:element.id},function(err, output) {

            let useraction = output.toObject();       
            useraction.role=element.role;             
            useraction.email=element.email;
            useraction.userid=element._id;

            userData.push(useraction);
            callback();       
          });
        },(err)=>{
          if (err) return next(err);
          res.json(userData);
        });

      });

    });
```